# Save path to reuse on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, path

I am working on a canvas. I permit draw paths like this:

```
// when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
    private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
        trazo.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    // when ACTION_MOVE move touch according to the x,y values
    private void moveTouch(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOLERANCE || dy >= TOLERANCE) {
            trazo.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    // when ACTION_UP stop touch
    private void upTouch() {
        trazo.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCircles.add(new Trazo(trazo, colorActual, pincel));
        trazo = new Path();
    }
```

I want to save this "trazo" in local DB to reuse later on a canvas. 
How can i save it? I think if a save the first point (x,y) and second point (x,y), it only will draw a line between two points. I need to save all the path. 
I dont want save canvas as image because i want to reuse it later and permit modify it.

Comment: Track each path and add create json of each path and save it all as one row in the sqlite database.

Comment: i will try do it with gson. if this doesnt work i will try with you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I save an ArrayList of Points and then I iterate this List to construct the Path.

Comment: can you give an example?  @garciam202

Answer (score 1):

You can marshal you trazo object to json using google Gson.
Gradle dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Usage:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String trazoJson = gson.toJson(trazo);
```

Then you can persist you `trazoJson` to database and you can easily unmarshal `trazoJson` to `trazo` as.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Path trazo = gson.fromJson(trazoJson, Path.class);
```

Comment: This not works for me. Json doesnt transform well the Path

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the path as String like in svg.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths